# ACTION_GET_CONTENT supported mime types?

Tags: android, mime-types

I'm trying to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT with [text/csv mime type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111) but the result is that all files are displayed but grayed out in the file picker?

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/csv");
...
currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE, Bundle.EMPTY);
```

Tested on Android 7.1/8/9 with the same outcome. The following directory contains .json and .csv files.

[image]

Is this mime type even supported?

Comment: You prooved it is not.

Comment: While if you are using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT then you can able to see all the files but you cannot able to select it!!!

Comment: You posted a screendump to show us that .json and .csv files are not selectable? Or what intention did you have?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a csv is explicitly supported, instead you can just treat it as a normal plaintext file, and parse the content yourself like this:

```
intent.setType("text/*");
```

The downside is that the non-csv files will also be shown to the user, therefore, you might need to do some extra checking for the contents of the file.
If you really do need it to be a .csv being shown to the user, you can create your own file picking activity that filter everything else that does not have the .csv extension.

Comment: It seems to be supported by third party providers, like the file manager of my Redmi Not 6 Pro. I need to find one for other phones.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported still (tested on Android 8). But it's better this than nothing. At least it grays out other files that are obviously not text on the default document selector.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Android seems to only recognize "text/comma-separated-values". Here's how I fixed it,

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);    
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimetypes = {"text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```